# Using onclick only on parent element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a modal display when a button is clicked and I'd like to close it when the user clicks outside of the content area.  Right now I have

```
<div id="modal" onclick="hideModal(this.id)">
    <div id="modal_content">
        <h1>Update Weight</h1>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" name="weight" maxlength=4/> lbs
            <input type="Submit" value="Update"/>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- modal_content -->
</div> <!-- modal -->
```

And my simple javascript function is

```
function hideModal(selected) {
modal = document.getElementById("modal");
modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

The problem with this is the modal gets hidden even when any of the parent elements are clicked.

Comment: Can you post your entire code please?

Comment: Did you try <div id="modal_content" onclick="hideModal(this.id)"> instead of <div id="modal" onclick="hideModal(this.id)">?

Comment: well you need to stop propagation....

Comment: @PhaniKumarM My entire code is too long.  This should be all that is relevant for this problem.

Comment: @Yogesh The "this.id" was actually more of a test to see if the returned id would change based on where I clicked, and I had the onclick event setup for each child element, but unfortunately I only got "modal" back, regardless of where I clicked.

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, closing the modal when you click outside the modal's main component is the default behaviour (you're not doing that, it is the bootstrap library).

Comment: @epascarello That sounds correct but could you please elaborate?  I googled some examples but I wasn't able to follow along. It'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @Titus I am not using bootstrap, just custom css and basic javascript so far.

Comment: "close modal when click outside" Probably 20 previous questions with answers that explain it.

Comment: @Titus The problem is I get "modal" as the selected element regardless of where I click. :/

Comment: @epascarello I have looked and most use jquery or the explanation does not make sense to me, hence why I decided to post for myself, hoping someone could explain it based on my exact code and situation...

Comment: Add a click handler to the body so it hides the modal. Add a click handler to the modal and do https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to keep the event from traveling down to the other event listeners.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
document.body.addEventListener("click", function () {
  modal.classList.remove("active");
})

modal.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
});
```

```css
#modal {
  display :none;
}

#modal.active {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div id="modal" class="active">Hi</div>
```

Comment: I am a bit confused (I am still learning javscript).  Right now, my js is in a different .js file.  Will the event listener still be added right on the page load?  Or do I need additional js within my html file? I am also a bit confused on why the event is called twice?

Comment: I tried adding this code but it did not work.  I really don't mean to be difficult but there is no explanation of what is happening or where the code belongs.    Your example doesn't include any children elements to prove it is working.  I do believe you're on the right track considering other similar threads also mention the stopPropagation method, but, for whatever reason, the concept is just not clicking for me (pun).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div id="modal" onclick="hideModal(event)">
    ....
</div>


function hideModal(event) {
    if(event.target.id == "modal"){
        event.target.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it still closes the modal regardless of where I click.  I'm still learning javascript and I'm not sure what the 'event' is passing exactly.

Comment: @SchweeDubulus `event` is the mouse click event and `event.target` is the actual HTML element that was clicked which means that this code will only execute the statement `event.target.style.display = "none";` when the HTML element with the ID `modal` is clicked. If this still doesn't do what you want is probably because the `div` with the ID `modal` spans more then you realise (is bigger then you think).

Comment: Well the way I am taking it is that the "modal" div contains the "modal_content" div, which contains the h1 tag and form elements.  So clicking any of the children still triggers the onclick event of the parent, which makes sense.  What I find odd though, is that the returned id is "modal" regardless of which element is clicked.

Comment: @SchweeDubulus If you click something other then the `div` with the ID `modal` the `if` statement will no longer be `true`. You can find more details about `event.target` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: @SchweeDubulus What I means is that if you click on the `div` with the ID `modal_content`, `event.target.id` will be equal to `modal_content`. Make sure that `modal`'s `z-index` doesn't put it on top of all other elements.

Comment: I just tried it again and of course it works now.  I probably messed something up before but thanks a ton.  Side note:  Interestingly enough, clicking the submit button automatically closes the modal.  I am skeptical of my codes intuition...hah.

Comment: @SchweeDubulus I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to mark this answer if it solved your problem. I'm not sure what is going on with the `submit` button, it is not evident why it will close the modal from the code that you've posted.